# JS - Intercept all incoming XML and Websocket request client-side

Tags: javascript

I am working on a web proxy right now and it works, but I need some Javascript that could see all incoming XML, Fetch, and websocket request and rewrite them. Only problem is that I don't know how to. I really need this in pure javascript. I apologize if I can't show any code here.

Comment: You need it on the server side?
Or a client side (web-app interceptor) for all requests?

Comment: I need it client side please

Comment: Try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Intercept_HTTP_requests

Answer (score 1):

if you want to read the content of the requests, you need to set up a web server.

you can use http and websocket module to set up a simple server,

but I recommend using a backend framework, such as express.

Comment: I need it client-side. I know its possible since I have seen it.

Comment: @jasoncornwall yeah, implement a backend server on the client side. I know it sound weird but it's not.